# How to have two 'access levels' on a model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, activerecord

Let's assume a simple and common scenario.

I have a `User` model with an `admin` field. Users cannot edit their `admin` field, but admins can edit anyone's `admin` field.

So, I need to give both types of users appropriate access.

If I'd present this in a RESTful way, I'd have two resources, say

```
resource :user
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

...And here comes the dilemma - how do I control where the `admin` field can be changed and where not?

1. I can set `attr_protected :admin` to prevent users from changing their admin status. But then I'd have to make a special case out of it in `Admin::UsersController`, like

   ```
   @user.admin = params[:user][:admin]
   ```
2. I can scrub the parameter in the `UsersController`, which is even worse

   ```
   params[:user].delete(:admin)
   ```

Both of these solutions look messy to me. What's the correct way of dealing with such situations?

What if there's more than 2 access levels?

Comment: have you tried ACL plugins like devise or declarative_authorization to ease your troubles?

Comment: well, Devise only handles authentication, and declarative_authorization works on per-model level, while I want control on a per-field level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Rails 3.1 will have exactly what I wanted.

http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/05/12/activerecord-3-1-mass-assignment-roles/

Answer (score 2):

how about subclassing? maybe try something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :columns, :that, :are, :safe, :for, :users
end

class AdminUser < User
    attr_accessible :admin
end
```

then use the appropriate model in each controller. note using attr_protected in the User class won't work in this scenario since AR doesn't (currently) intelligently apply them, it will complain that :admin can only be in one. using attr_accessible is generally better practice anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reworking your resources to look something like:

```
users/guest
users/user
users/admin
```

where

```
admin<user
```

and

```
user<guest
```

Building on Jon's excellent answer, you could try something like the following:

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :columns, :that, :are, :safe, :for, :guests
  attr_reader :is_admin
end

class User < Guest
  attr_accessible :more, :stuff, :for, :users
end

class AdminUser < User
  attr_accessible :some, :adminThings, :here
  attr_writer :is_admin
end
```

... and then AdminUser will inherit attr_read for :is_admin from Guest.

Hope that helps -

Perry